# Chunk Array into groups - what's wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, loops, logic

Below is the code :

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
  var newArr =[];
  for(var i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
    for(var j = 0;j < size;j++){
      newArr.push(arr.splice(0,size));
    }
  }
  var result = [];
  for(i = 0;i < newArr.length;i++){
    if(newArr[i].length != 0){
      result.push(newArr[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8], 2);
```

This should return - `[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8]]`. However, the code returns `[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]`. Also, if my input array is ([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],2) my code returns as expected.

P.S: I am specifically looking to find what's wrong with this code instead of a different code/approach altogether.

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Your actual and expected outputs are identical. Typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need just one loop, because you splice the array and take a chunk of the wanted size of it.

This behaviour could be used to loop until the array has a length of zero and exit the loop.

In this case the result is ready.

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
    var newArr = [];
    // for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    while (arr.length) {                        // add this for looping and checking
        // for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        newArr.push(arr.splice(0, size));       // keep this for doing the work!
        // }
    }
    // var result = [];
    // for (i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
    //     if (newArr[i].length != 0) {
    //         result.push(newArr[i]);
    //     }
    // }
    // return result;
    return newArr;                              // return only newArray
}

console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the following:

```
var size = 2;
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var newArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=size){
    newArray.push(arr.slice(i,i+size))
}
console.log(newArray); //will output [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7],[8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not treating the case where the remaining in the array is less than the given `size`, in other words the case when `arr.length < size`, so the remaining items in the array won't be taken into account in the chunk array.

You need to test upon it, I updated your code so it works perfectly:

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
  var newArr =[];
  while(size<arr.length){
      newArr.push(arr.splice(0, size ));
  }
  if(arr.length<size){
      newArr.push(arr);
  }

}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
  var newArr =[];
  while(size<arr.length){
      newArr.push(arr.splice(0, size));
  }
  if(arr.length<size){
      newArr.push(arr);
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8], 2));
```

**Note:**

There's no need for using the `result` array as it's just a copy of the `newArr`, you could just return `newArr` without copying it.

Comment: The ternary condition is not necessary there, splice will only cut as many elements as there is, the `arr.length` is also not necessary unless size were a negative value (that'd be a better condition IMO)

Comment: @MinusFour Thank you for pointing it out, the ternary operation, was there for a testing reason before using the `while` loop, I just forgot to delete it, but you are right for the `arr.length`, I updated the answer.